# Can we relate $\mathbb{E}\|\mathbf{x}\|$ with $\mathbb{E}\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have just learned about expected values of random vectors. I apologize if my intuition is a bit incorrect. So we know by superposition property of expected values that :
$$
\mathbb{E}\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}=\mathbb{E}\{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+\cdots+x_{n}^{2}\}=\mathbb{E}\{x_{1}^{2}\}+\mathbb{E}\{x_{2}^{2}\}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}\{x_{n}^{2}\}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a random $n\times1$ matrix.

My question is if we know that $\mathbb{E}\{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}\}$ has some upper bound $\alpha$, is there a way to deduce an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}\{\|\mathbf{x}\|\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is concave on $[0, \infty)$. Hence by Jensen's inequality,
$$E(\|\textbf{x}\|) = E(\sqrt{\|\textbf{x}\|^2}) \leq\sqrt{E(\|\textbf{x}\|^2)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{E}\|x\|^2 - \left(\mathbb{E}\|x\|\right)^2= \text{Var}\|x\| \ge 0$, we have $(\mathbb{E}\|x\|)^2 \le \mathbb{E}\|x\|^2$, and so, $\mathbb{E}\|x\| \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\|x\|^2} \le \sqrt{\alpha}$.